# How to add multiple checkbox array field in rails application and showing on view page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I have made a rails application in I have made an option of multiple checkboxes and stores those entries in an array. But things are not working out. Here is my code:
It is showing Nonameerror as undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass on the line in show page <%= @branches.each do |t| %>
New Form:

```
  </p>
  <%= f.label :allowedBranches %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  :allowedBranches,{}, value='COE'%><%= f.label :COE %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  :allowedBranches,{}, value='ECE'%><%= f.label :ECE %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  :allowedBranches,{}, value='ICE'%><%= f.label :ICE %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  :allowedBranches,{}, value='IT'%><%= f.label :IT %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  :allowedBranches,{}, value='MPAE'%><%= f.label :MPAE %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  :allowedBranches,{}, value='BT'%><%= f.label :BT %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  :allowedBranches,{}, value='IS'%><%= f.label :IS %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  :allowedBranches,{}, value='SP'%><%= f.label :SP %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  :allowedBranches,{}, value='PC'%><%= f.label :PC %><br>
  <p>
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @company = Company.new
end

def edit

    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    if @company.update(company_params)
        redirect_to @company
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def create

    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    if @company.save
        redirect_to @company
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def index
    @companies = Company.all
end
def destroy
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    @company.destroy

    redirect_to companies_path
end

def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    @branches = @company.collect(:allowedBranches)
end
private
    def company_params

        params.require(:company).permit(:name, :beCutoff,:grade,:xiiCutoff,:xCutoff,:backsAllowed,:details,:package,:deadline,allowedBranches:[]) if params[:company]
    end
```

Show Page:

```
<p>
<strong>Allowed Branches:</strong>
<%= @branches.each do |t| %>
 <%= puts t %>
<% end %>
</p>
```

I also want that whenever I edit the form, I get the same checkboxes checked.

Logs are

```
Started PATCH "/companies/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:09 +0530
Processing by CompaniesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"92w4xJiuRFYvTWRmawnMQLeDdszKHE6szmq0GhTRFaY=", "company"=>{"name"=>"Facebook", "grade"=>"dream", "beCutoff"=>"70.0", "backsAllowed"=>"0", "details"=>"Apply online", "package"=>"93.0", "xiiCutoff"=>"60.0", "xCutoff"=>"60.0", "deadline"=>"2014-06-29 00:50:45"}, "allowedBranches"=>"{}", "commit"=>"Update Company", "id"=>"15"}
  [1m[36mCompany Load (5.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 15]]
  [1m[35m (2.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (3.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/companies/15
Completed 302 Found in 65ms (ActiveRecord: 10.0ms)


Started GET "/companies/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:09 +0530
Processing by CompaniesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"15"}
  [1m[35mCompany Load (2.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
  Rendered companies/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 431ms (Views: 418.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-theme.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:10 +0530


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-theme.min.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:11 +0530


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:11 +0530


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:11 +0530


Started GET "/assets/companies.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:11 +0530


Started GET "/assets/students.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:11 +0530


Started GET "/assets/welcome.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:11 +0530


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:11 +0530


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:11 +0530


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:11 +0530


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/companies.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ar-ma.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ar.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.bg.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.br.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.bs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.by.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ca.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.cs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.cv.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:12 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.da.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.de.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.el.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.en-au.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.en-ca.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.en-gb.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.eo.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.es.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.et.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.eu.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fa.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fi.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr-ca.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:13 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.gl.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.he.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.hi.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.hr.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.hu.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.id.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.is.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.it.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ja.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ka.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ko.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.lt.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.lv.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ml.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:14 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.mr.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ms-my.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.nb.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ne.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.nl.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.nn.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pl.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ro.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ru.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.sk.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.sl.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:15 +0530


Started GET "/assets/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.sq.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 00:54:16 +0530
```

Migration to add allowedBranches to table companies

```
class AddbanchesAllowedArraytoCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :companies, :allowedBranches, :string, :array=>true
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you get any error? And also post the generated server logs while submitting the form.

Comment: At this code it is showing error as noname error pointing at show page <%= @branches.each do |t| %> --line

Comment: But when I remove this line by <%= @company.allowedBranches %> it works properly but nothing is saved i suppose

Comment: Can you post the exact error in the question please?

Comment: not `<%= @branches.each do |t| %>` this render each use `<% @branches.each do |t| %>`.

Comment: I am not able to save the field allowedBranches[] in array. Plus I am not able to show this on view page.

Comment: @PhilidorGreen Again it is showing Nonameerror

Comment: What is that Nonameerror?.Please post the exact error in the question.

Comment: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass "it is showing error as noname error pointing at show page <%= @branches.each do |t| %> --line"

Comment: Try removing the `{}` from all `check_box_tag` and check.

Comment: `Undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` means your `@branches` variable is nil. If that's nil, then your `@company.collect(:allowedBranches)` is also nil so what exactly are you expecting that line to do? Pull all of a particular company's "allowedBranches" objects? Collect is usually used on an array, not an individual object.

Comment: yes exactly. I also don't know if collect(:allowedBranches) will work or not?

Comment: It shouldn't. How are your allowedBranches being stored? Are they an array stored with each Company object? if so simple `@company.allowedBranches` or something along those lines should work. Perhaps if you posted your Company class file it might make things easier

Comment: yes allowedBranches is defined as an array. I have made a migration to add a field allowedBranch as string array. I'll update it on question

Comment: you "usually" want to avoid storing arrays in your database, but not always. However I would suggest creating a `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship if at all possible.

Before doing that however try using `@company.allowedBranches` and see what you get.

Comment: @company.allowedBranches removes that undefined method error but does not render any value on show page

Comment: You're show page says `puts t` which shorts the output to the view page and places it into the console instead. Remove the puts or check your console for data output i believe.

Comment: I removed put. It shows 'undefined method `collect' for' on controller page

Comment: undefined collect for what? for nil class? For company? What line causes the error? did you not remove the `@branches = @company.collect(:allowedBranches)` line?

Comment: No I haven't. undefined method `collect' for #<Company:0x4a13d80>

Comment: Then that's your problem. You can't call "collect" on a single object. It has to be an array or an enumerable.

Comment: I saw this method somewhere for storing array. I am not able to find any other method for this. In fact 'find' or 'all' methods are also not working

Comment: Alright, I believe we've passed the ability of this site to answer your question. The errors are increasing instead of decreasing. Try to limit everything down to a root cause and come back with a new question. I honestly believe shifting over to a has_many belongs_to relationship would help a lot here.

Comment: I know, being a beginner I sometimes get out of things. I appreciate your help. I hope I'll solve it myself now.

Comment: No worries, everyone starts somewhere. However you learn best when you solve your own mistakes and only ask help when you're truly stuck. I believe you can figure this one out no problem so good luck!

Comment: I know, I spent the whole day in figuring the problem but I was not getting a good references. I would appreciate if you can tell me good and easy references to learn stuffs like handling complex forms and database migrations in ruby on rails.

Comment: Check out gems like simple_form or semantic form if you cannot figure out how to use rails' built in form helpers.

Comment: thanks @benastan it will surely help

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems here.

Firstly, you're mixing your form with the `form_tag` and `form_for`. The difference is you're doing a `do |f| %>` at the end of the form tag.

What I mean is, you should have `<%= f.check_box ... %>` instead of `<%= check_box_tag ... %>`

Secondly, your value you're inputting is `{}` for each check box and creating `value=WHATEVER` which is not part of the options for the check_box_tag. To solve this:

```
  <%= check_box_tag  "allowedBranches[]", 'COE'%><%= label_tag :COE %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  "allowedBranches[]", 'ECE'%><%= label_tag :ECE %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  "allowedBranches[]", 'ICE'%><%= label_tag :ICE %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  "allowedBranches[]", 'IT'%><%= label_tag :IT %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  "allowedBranches[]", 'MPAE'%><%= label_tag :MPAE %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  "allowedBranches[]", 'BT'%><%= label_tag :BT %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  "allowedBranches[]", 'IS'%><%= label_tag :IS %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  "allowedBranches[]", 'SP'%><%= label_tag :SP %><br>
  <%= check_box_tag  "allowedBranches[]", 'PC'%><%= label_tag :PC %><br>
```

Which will actually create an array params for you. Then you can loop through it

Comment: It is showing error as undefined method `merge' for 'COE':String

Comment: Your answer is logical but it is not helping me get forms working

Comment: You have nilClass in the .each loop cause your form is saving '{}'

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed El Mahallawy for help. I just figured out that using array to store data is a bad option, all sql do not support it. I am moving to a new approach. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: To the contrary, I'd suggest you explore Postgresql's JSON data type http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html